# Order of propositions in a logic tree

Tags: logic, trees

Does the order of propositions in a logic tree matter? For eg. If I wanted to test validity and I negated my conclusion, does it matter where this negated conclusion goes?

Thanks

Comment: No, it doesn't. The tree must start wit the list of all premises and the negation of the conclusion.